# Declaring variables slow down program

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program which uses a RichTextBox (which is part of Tab Control) and in the TextChanged event I these variable declarations:

```
RichTextBox programTextBox = (RichTextBox)tabControl.TabPages[tabControl.SelectedIndex].Controls[0];
int selectStart = programTextBox.SelectionStart;
int programCurrentLine = programTextBox.GetLineFromCharIndex(programTextBox.SelectionStart);
int programCurrentLineIndex = programTextBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(programCurrentLine);
int programCurrentLineLength = programTextBox.Lines[programCurrentLine].Length;
string programCurrentLineText = programTextBox.Lines[programCurrentLine].ToString();
```

All of them are important in that particular event and I use them multiple times for multiple purposes. However, recalculating every single time slows down my program.

For example, I've noticed that if I open a somewhat large file (with my RichTextBox) and then start pressing e.g. the 'a' button, there is some noticable lag. Deleting every single piece of code except the declaration of these variables does not help at all with the lag, but also deleting the code above, completely solves the problem.

I have two questions: 1) Why do these declarations slow down that much the TextChanged event and 2) What can I do? (Is there a faster way to calculate these variables?)

Comment: What are you trying to do? That *program* word in the name of your variables makes me think you should use a specialized code editor instead of a `RichTextBox` which was never designed for such a task.

Comment: Well, I do a lot of stuff in that event like Syntax Highlighting and counting the total number of lines (which is displayed on the left), but as I said, even deleting every piece of code except for those declarations makes the event slow.

Comment: @Icemanind I did not make those two methods. I use the default ones that I was provided with when I started working on my program.

Comment: @OC_- Put that code in a separate thread.

Comment: @OC_ well, drop that `RichTextBox` (I'll never understand why people keep using it all the time) and use a proper component that was designed to handle code. AvalonEdit is really good, but it's a WPF component you'd have to host in your form, so you may want to try a WinForms one - I've read somewhere there's a Scintilla-based solution out there.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the variable declarations - it's the code you're using to initialize them. I wouldn't be at *all* surprised to find that `GetLineFromCharIndex` and `GetFirstCharIndexFromLine` were expensive - and currently you're calling the `Lines` property twice.

You could probably improve matters at least slightly just by removing one of those `Lines` calls, simply by fetching the line first and then looking at its length:

```
// No need to call ToString() - Lines is a string[]
string programCurrentLineText = programTextBox.Lines[programCurrentLine];
int programCurrentLineLength = programCurrentLineText.Length;
```

It's a shame there isn't some way of saying "Get all the information about the position of the given index: its line, first char index from line, and the line itself" in one call :(

Comment: I used the code that you wrote and I also replaced the `programTextBox.SelectionStart` with `selectStart` since I've already calculated it (very stupid of me), but there barely was any improvement. I guess that `GetLineFromCharIndex` and `GetFirstCharIndexFromLine` are the ones that slow down my program. I may actually have to take a look at the way they work and see if I make new ones...

Comment: @OC_: Now would be a time to stop guessing and *measure*, of course. Whenever you run into a performance problem, you should start taking measurements. Profilers are helpful, but you don't necessarily need one - just call each of your methods (separately) thousands of times and see how long it takes... then you can be certain which of them are the most problematic. I suspect you won't find a really good solution to this though - I doubt that `RichTextBox` is really amenable to this sort of work.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not important to recalculate on every key press you might be better off implementing a boolean variable which is set on keypress then has a timer to reset it. For example adding a 1.2 second delay on the event. I am not sure the needs of your app so that time might be a bit much.

Comment: Although a 1.2 second delay would be too much for my program, I also thought that using an if statement to avoid recalculating those variables when it is sure that they will wield the same results. I will give this a try and post the results if it helps.